# Type mismatch (String) using case class and actor

Tags: string, scala, akka

Some format issue when I'm trying to quote the code, so here is the picture :(

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GAYi.jpg)

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}

case class Number(n: Int)
case class String(s: String)

class DoublingActor extends Actor {
  def receive: Receive = {
    case Number(n) => println(s"Result of doubling $n: ${n*2}")
    case String(s) => println(s"Result of doubling $s: ${s}${s}")
  }
}

object Double extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("DoublerSystme")
  val doubler = system.actorOf(Props[DoublingActor], "doubler")

  doubler ! Number(5)
  doubler ! String("test")
}
```

The thing is, the actor works fine with number, but how can I add the matching function that returns the string twice?

Answer (score 1):

What behavior are you seeing?  Due to your issue being wrapped in an image, I can't test for sure, but I'd expect that you are getting a compile error with the descriptive message `object String is not a case class, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq member`.

Because it doesn't have the `unapply` member, you'll need to  modify your statement to

```
case s: String => println(s"Result of doubling $s: ${s}:${s}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid naming your case class as `String`, especially in your case, with `String` parameter type:

```
case class String(s: String)
```

It would confuse the compiler to expect a parameter type different from the actual `String` type you want.  Your app will work if you explicitly specify `java.lang.String` as the parameter type:

```
case class String(s: java.lang.String)
```

In any case, I would not recommend naming a case class as `String`.