# Scala type(String) mismatch

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to implement a simple example using Akka, doubling a number here looks fine, but duplicating a string introduces an error:

*type mismatch; found : String (in java.lang) required: String (in )*

Here is the code snippet:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type mismatch (String) using case class and actor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48571375/type-mismatch-string-using-case-class-and-actor)

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. sorry to lead off with a scold, but: please never post screen shots of code, they aren't searchable. paste in actual code, please.

Answer (score 2):

Your `String` case class shadows `java.lang.String` so it is not visible. It should be more obvious if you write it like this:

```
case class MyClass(s: MyClass)

MyClass("java.lang.String")
```

You can use full name to handle that

```
case class String(s: java.lang.String)
```

or just use name that doesn't collide with basic, build-in types' names.